# How To Only Address One Element In A Parent Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I am working on a simple to-do list and when I click the check box next to the new item, both the text and the delete button gain the strikethrough property. Is there a way for me to make it so that only the text gets the strikethrough, and not the delete button?

I have tried targeting specific children but I am still learning and might have done this wrong. I can't figure out how to only target the text item and not the delete button.

**Snippet**

```js
let taskList = document.getElementById('taskList');
let taskBox = document.getElementById('taskBox');
let taskCount = 0;

document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    addTask();
  }
});

function addTask() {
  let taskVal = taskBox.value;

  if (taskVal.length < 1) {
    window.alert('Task Box Empty');
  } else {
    let itemDiv = document.createElement('li');
    let itemCheck = document.createElement('input');
    let textItem = document.createTextNode(taskVal);
    let itemDelete = document.createElement('button');

    itemDiv.classList.add('itemDiv');

    itemCheck.style.height = "50px";

    itemCheck.type = "checkbox";
    itemCheck.name = "finished";
    itemCheck.id = "checkbox";

    textItem.innerText = taskVal;
    itemDelete.innerText = "x"

    taskList.append(itemDiv);
    itemDiv.appendChild(itemCheck);
    itemDiv.appendChild(textItem);
    itemDiv.appendChild(itemDelete);
    taskCount++;

    itemCheck.onclick = finishTask.bind(itemCheck);
    itemDelete.onclick = deleteItem.bind(itemDiv);
    document.getElementById('taskBox').innerHTML = "";

    taskBox.value = "";
  }
}

function finishTask() {
  let children = this.parentNode.children;
  if (this.checked) {
    this.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  } else {
    this.parentNode.style.textDecoration = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>My To-Do List</h1>
<hr>
<div class="addTaskContainer">
  <input id="taskBox" type="textarea" placeholder="Add Task" autocomplete="off">
  <button class="add" onClick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
</div>

<ul class="taskList" id="taskList"></ul>

<button class="bottomBtn" onClick="clearAll()">Clear All</button>

<button class="bottomBtn" onClick="clearFinished(itemCheck)">Clear Finished</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to wrap your text in a span.

First, remove this line

```
let textItem = document.createTextNode(taskVal);
```

and replace it with a span

```
let textItem = document.createElement('span');
textItem.innerText = taskVal;
```

Then target span your span in parent node.

```
function finishTask() {
  let textNode = this.parentNode.querySelector('span')
  if (this.checked) {
    textNode.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
  } else {
    textNode.style.textDecoration = 'none';
  }

  // OR simply
//   let textNode = this.parentNode.querySelector('span')
//   textNode.style.textDecoration = this.checked ? 'line-through' : 'none';

}
```